# Combining two queries without using Union

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g

I have two queries and want to combine these two queries without using "`UNION`"

for example

query 1:

```
Select
    T1.Field1,T1.Field2,T2.Field3
from
    T1, T2, T3
where T1.XYZ = T2.XYZ AND T1.STATUS = 'S' AND T1.XYZ = T3.XYZ AND T3.ABC = 'Y';
```

Result : 10 rows

query 2:

```
Select
    T1.Field1,T1.Field2,T2.Field3
from
    T1, T2, T4
where
    T1.XYZ = T2.XYZ AND T1.STATUS = 'W' AND T1.XYZ = T4.XYZ AND T4.ABC = 'Y';
```

Result : 5 rows.

Is there a way to combine query 1 and query 2 into single without using "`UNION`" and get the result as 15 (10+5).

Thanks in advance

Comment: What `RDBMS` are you using?

Comment: *Never* use comma's in the from, *always* use explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: My feeling is no - you have to use a union (or union all).

Comment: What purpose does T3 and T4 serve?  They are not actually limiting any data from T1 or T2 since you're doing a cross join and theirs no relation to T1 or T2; Since you're not displaying any data from T3 or T4; I can't figure out why it's even in either query.  Does the cross join inflate the record quantity by some needed number? asthere are multiple records with ABC = Y in T3 and T5?  (I'd need sample set of data to figure this out w/o a union)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I have updated my queries.

Comment: @user7194270, depending upon your latest change, I have modified the answer. You can have a look.

Comment: What's wrong with `UNION`?

Answer (score 2):

Just change your query like following.

```
select t1.field1, 
       t1.field2, 
       t2.field3 
from 
       t1, 
       t2, 
       t3 
where  t1.xyz = t2.xyz 
AND   (t1.status = 'S' OR t1.status = 'W') 
AND    t3.abc = 'Y'
```

**Edit 1:**

After knowing that one table is different, in both the queries. Following should work. I have changed comma's to `JOINS`.

```
select t1.field1, 
       t1.field2, 
       t2.field3 
from   t1 t1 
       inner join t2 t2 
               on t1.xyz = t2.xyz         
where  t1.status IN ( 'S', 'W' )
```

I agree with @xQbert that `CROSS JOIN` with t3 and t4 is not required. Even if it is increases the number or records but I can't think of any reason to use these tables in this particular query.

**Edit 2:** After the new updates in the question, following query should work

```
select t1.field1, 
       t1.field2, 
       t2.field3 
from   t1 t1 
       inner join t2 t2  on t1.xyz = t2.xyz 
       left join t3 t3 on t1.xyz = t3.xyz and t3.abc = 'Y'
       left join  t4 t4 on  t1.xyz = t4.xyz and t4.abc = 'Y'
where  t1.status IN ( 'S', 'W' )
and (t3.xyz is not null or t4.xyz is not null)
```

Comment: In the first query and second query 3rd table is different. 1st query it is T3 and 2nd query it is T4

Comment: What's the point of either left join at all then?  no select from T3 or T4.  and since it's a left join you're not limiting data in T1, T2...

Comment: @xQbert, you are right it is not making any sense, I will update the answer.

Comment: Is there a reason for aliasing table `t1` to `t1` and table `t2` to `t2`?

Comment: @PeterAbolins no specific reason, this is just I normally follow. Table name used was t1, t2 ,t3, I din't got a good alias name for the tables.

Answer (score 1):

It can be written as:

```
Select T1.Field1,T1.Field2,T2.Field3 
from T1, T2, T3, T4 
where T1.XYZ = T2.XYZ 
AND T1.STATUS IN('W','S') 
AND (T4.ABC = 'Y' OR T3.ABC = 'Y')
```